# Why can I only read data from the register if I use a printf?

Tags: c, driver, i2c, gpio

Im trying to set the gpio levels on the PCA9575. For some reason I have to include a printf before I call the read function for it to work correctly. I would like to be able to set the pins without a including printf statement.

Main Function:

```c
int main()
{
    PCA9575_begin(PCA9575_ADDR0);
    PCA9575_set_port_direction(0, OUTPUT);
    PCA9575_set_port_level(0, PCA9575_LEVEL_LOW);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {   
        PCA9575_set_gpio_level(i+28, 1);
        sleep_ms(500);
        PCA9575_set_gpio_level(i+28, 0);
        sleep_ms(500);
    }
}
```

Set GPIO Level Function:

```c
void PCA9575_set_gpio_level(uint8_t gpio_num, uint8_t level) 
{
    uint8_t reg, data;
    
    if (gpio_num > 27 && gpio_num < 36) {
        reg = OUT0;
        gpio_num = 1 << ((gpio_num - 27) -1);
        PCA9575_set_pin_direction(0, gpio_num, OUTPUT);
    }

    else if (gpio_num > 35 && gpio_num < 44) {
        reg = OUT1;
        gpio_num = 1 << ((gpio_num - 35) -1);
        PCA9575_set_pin_direction(1, gpio_num, OUTPUT);
    }

    printf("\ngpio_num: %d\n", gpio_num); // Before Function
    data = PCA9575_read_register(OUT0);
    // printf("\ngpio_num: %d\n", gpio_num); // After Function
    
    if(!data) data = level * gpio_num;
    else if(data == 0xff && level == 1) data = 0xff;
    else {
      if (level == 1) data = data ^gpio_num;
      else if (level == 0) data = data & (gpio_num ^ 0xFF);
    }
    
    PCA9575_write_to_register(reg, data);
}
```

Set Port Direction Function:

```c
void PCA9575_set_port_direction(uint8_t port, uint8_t direction) {
  uint8_t reg, data;

  if (port == 0) reg = CFG0;
  else reg = CFG1;

  if (direction == INPUT) data = 0b11111111;
  else data = 0b00000000;

  PCA9575_write_to_register(reg, data);
}
```

Set Pin Direction Function:

```c
void PCA9575_set_pin_direction(uint8_t port, uint8_t pin, uint8_t direction) {

  uint8_t reg, data;
  data = PCA9575_read_register(OUT0);

  if (port == 0) {
    reg = CFG0;
    if (direction == INPUT) data = data | pin;
    else if (direction == OUTPUT) data = data & ~pin;
  } 
  else if (port == 1) {
    reg = CFG1;
    if (direction == INPUT) data = data | pin;
    else if (direction == OUTPUT) data = data & ~pin;
  } 

  PCA9575_write_to_register(reg, data);
}
```

Set Port Level Function:

```c
void PCA9575_set_port_level(uint8_t port, uint8_t level) {

  uint8_t reg;

  if (port == 0) reg = OUT0;
  else if (port == 1) reg = OUT1;

  if (level == PCA9575_LEVEL_HIGH) level = INPUT;
  else if (level == PCA9575_LEVEL_LOW) level = OUTPUT;

  PCA9575_write_to_register(reg, level);
}
```

Read Register Function:

```c
uint8_t PCA9575_read_register(uint8_t reg) {
  uint8_t buf[1] = {0};

  i2c_begin(); // Begin I2C Communications
  i2c_set_addr(SLAVE_ADDRESS); // Set the I2C Address
  i2c_transmit(&reg, 1); // Transmit Message
  sleep_ms(1);  // Sleep 1 ms

  i2c_recieve(buf, 1); // Receive Message from Slave
  i2c_end(); // End I2C Communications
  return buf[1]; // Return the message
}
```

Write to Register Function:

```
void PCA9575_write_to_register(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data){

  uint8_t command[] = {reg, data};

  i2c_begin(); // Begin I2C Communications
  i2c_set_addr(SLAVE_ADDRESS); // Set the I2C Address
  i2c_transmit(command, 2); // Transmit Message
  i2c_end(); // End I2C Communications
}
```

What I get with the printf statement before read function is called.

```
gpio_num: 1
data: 0X01

gpio_num: 1
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 2
data: 0X02

gpio_num: 2
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 4
data: 0X04

gpio_num: 4
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 8
data: 0X08

gpio_num: 8
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 16
data: 0X10

gpio_num: 16
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 32
data: 0X20

gpio_num: 32
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 64
data: 0X40

gpio_num: 64
data: 0X00

gpio_num: 128
data: 0X80

gpio_num: 128
data: 0X00
```

What I get with the printf statement after read function is called.

```
gpio_num: 1
data: 0X01

gpio_num: 1
data: 0X16

gpio_num: 2
data: 0X15

gpio_num: 2
data: 0X15

gpio_num: 4
data: 0X13

gpio_num: 4
data: 0X13

gpio_num: 8
data: 0X1F

gpio_num: 8
data: 0X17

gpio_num: 16
data: 0X07

gpio_num: 16
data: 0X07

gpio_num: 32
data: 0X37

gpio_num: 32
data: 0X17

gpio_num: 64
data: 0X57

gpio_num: 64
data: 0X17

gpio_num: 128
data: 0X97

gpio_num: 128
data: 0X17
```

Comment: `return buf[1]` index is out of bounds

Comment: Wow how did I miss that lol @stark thanks

Comment: Does anyone know why I was getting the correct output with a printf and didn't get an error?

Comment: `buf` is in the stack, and `buf[1]` is one byte beyond what you're allowed to read. The `printf` called before `read_register` alters the stack beyond the legal `buf[0]` in a way that in a lucky way makes the program work as you expect. But it is undefine behavior, meaning that this luck is unpredictable and it is unlikely to occur even in a slightly different scenario.

Comment: Is it Linux or some small microcontroller stuff?